# Array is initially empty, but after an entry in a text field which is used for filtering, it is full

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I verushc an array from one component to another component.
The initial array is filled by a DB and is not empty.
If I try to map over the array in my second component, it is empty (length = 0);
However, after I wrote a value in a search box to filter the array, all articles appear as intended.
What is that about?

```
export default function Einkäufe({ alleEinkäufe, ladeAlleEinkäufe, url }) {

const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = React.useState("");
const [searchResults, setSearchResults] = React.useState(alleEinkäufe);



const listeFiltern = (event) => {
setSearchTerm(event.target.value);
};

React.useEffect(() => {
setSearchResults(alleEinkäufe);
}, []);

React.useEffect(() => {
const results = alleEinkäufe.filter((eink) =>
  eink.artikel.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm.toLowerCase())
);
setSearchResults(results);
}, [searchTerm]);


[...]

   {searchResults.map((artikel, index) => {
        return ( ... );
      })}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with your useEffect hook that sets the list of searchResults, it's not rerun when alleEinkäufe property is updated. You need to add alleEinkäufe as it's dependency.

```js
  React.useEffect(() => {
    setSearchResults(alleEinkäufe);
  }, [alleEinkäufe]);
```

My bet is that the parent component that renders Einkäufe is initially passing an empty array which is used as searchResults state and then never updated since useEffect with empty dependencies array is only run once on the component's mount.

I would also advise you to use English variable and function names, especially when you ask for assistance because it helps others to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Your search term intially is `""`. All effects run when your components mount, including the effect which runs a filter. Initially, it's going to try to match any article to `""`.

You should include a condition to run your filter.

```js
React.useEffect(() => {
if (searchTerm) {
const results = alleEinkäufe.filter((eink) =>
  eink.artikel.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm.toLowerCase())
);
setSearchResults(results);
}
}, [searchTerm]);
```

BTW, `""` is falsy.

Comment: No, that wasn't the solution.
As I said, the constant "searchResults" is empty if I initially fill it with "all purchases" from another component, although "all purchases" is not empty